# Group by regex count

Tags: regex, sqlite

```
id
1001
2001
2002
3001
3002
3003
```

How to group the `id` column by its first digit `1, 2, 3`? I mean something like below:

```
select count(*) from my_tbl group by expr_id_1st_digit;

count(*)
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   (SELECT Substr(id, 1, 1) AS myGroup 
        FROM   table1) a 
GROUP  BY mygroup
```